# error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'map'

Tags: c++, dictionary, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting crazy. I just have a header and cpp and it doesn't compile:

the .h is the following:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <windows.h>



class Activate
{
public:
    Activate();
    ~Activate();

    int accion(map<string, string>& mapa);
};
```

and the cpp this one:

```
#include "Activate.h"
using namespace std;

Activate::Activate()
{
}


Activate::~Activate()
{
}

int Activate::accion(map<string, string>& mapa){}
```

and I get the error mentioned above:

> 1>c:\users\dani.roca\desktop\autocad files\mfc
>   dll\project1\project1\activate.h(19): error C2061: syntax error :
>   identifier 'map'
>  1>c:\users\dani.roca\desktop\autocad files\mfc
>   dll\project1\project1\activate.cpp(13): error C2511: 'int
>   Activate::accion(std::map<_Kty,_Ty> &)' : overloaded member function
>   not found in 'Activate'

---

```
#include "Activate.h"
using namespace std;

Activate::Activate()
{
}


Activate::~Activate()
{
}

int Activate::accion(std::map<string, string>& mapa){}
```

and this

```
class Activate
{
public:
    Activate();
    ~Activate();

    int accion(std::map<std::string, std::string>& mapa);
};
```

then new error appeared:

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Comment: where is main()? you can't compile without main(). main() is life.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki why should I? I am using namespace std already

Comment: "use namespace std" [should be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). It's sad how many uneducated instructors are teaching this bad programming practice to their students.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `int accion(map<string, string>& mapa);` with

```
int accion(std::map<std::string, std::string>& mapa);
//         ^^^^^    ^^^^^        ^^^^^
```

When you include your header, `using namespace std` is yet to take effect.

As an alternative you can add `using std::map;` and `using std::string;` in your class.

```
class Activate
{
public:
    Activate();
    ~Activate();

    using std::map;
    using std::string;
    int accion(map<string, string>& mapa);
};
```

Comment: Then you should say `using namespace std;` and then include the header. BTW never say `using namespace std;` in production code.

Comment: or in a header file.

Comment: changed this:

class Activate
{
public:
 Activate();
 ~Activate();

 int accion(std::map<std::string, std::string>& mapa);
};

#include "Activate.h"
using namespace std;

Activate::Activate()
{
}


Activate::~Activate()
{
}

int Activate::accion(std::map<string, string>& mapa){
}

and new error:
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Comment: You need a `main` function.

Comment: @MohitJain with main new error: 1>  LINK : C:\Users\dani.roca\Desktop\autocad Files\MFC DLL\Project1\x64\Debug\Activacion.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link